# SQLite: Calculating Percentage of E-Mail Providers

Tags: sqlite

I've got a table filled with E-Mail addresses and was wondering how I could calculate the percentage of each E-Mail provider (e.g. G-Mail, Yahoo etc) within the table? Currently, I have:

`COUNT(*)/SUM(Email) AS Percentage FROM Table GROUP BY Provider`

But it only returns NULL values

Answer (score 0):

If you have the domain as a column, then you can do:

```
select domain, count(*) / cnt as proportion
from t cross join
     (select count(*)*1.0 as cnt from t) x
group by domain, cnt;
```

If you don't have the domain, you can use string functions to extract it (your question seems to be more about the calculation than the domain extraction).

Comment: Worked great! Thank you ^_^